# Rails Action Mailer and returning Status 200 if the email was sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I have a Rails API, with the following Mailer:

```rb
  def demo_request
    @user = params[:user]

    mail(
        to: "foo@bar.com",
        subject: "[DEMO REQUEST] #{@user[:name]} - #{@user[:email]}",
        body: "A potential customer, #{@user[:name]}, requested a demo be sent to them. You can follow up with them at #{@user[:email]}",
        content_type: "text/html"
    )
  end
```

A very simple one, it is triggered by the following controller:

```rb
  class DemoRequestsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

    def create
      @user = params.permit(:email, :name)
      UserMailer.with(user: @user).demo_request.deliver_now
    end
  end
```

Also very simple, it simply invokes the Mailer upon receiving a POST request with some params. This API is being consumed by a client application, Rails Forms don't play a role here.

In testing, I can see that the Mailer seems to work alright, but the problem is that, obviously, the controller will return a `204: No Content` response.

What's the proper way to get the controller to return a `200 OK` response, only IF the Mailer was successful? Otherwise, return a 404 or error message or whatever else is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [`head :ok`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html) might be enough.

```
def create
  @user = params.permit(:email, :name)
  UserMailer.with(user: @user).demo_request.deliver_now
  head :ok
end
```

Because if sending the email fails then there would be a `500 ServerError` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear if your controller is being called from a client application (you handle it as a JSON api) or if it is plain rails forms.

If a json api/service, you can try to render the json back

```
begin
  UsererMailer.with(user: @user).demo_request.deliver_now
  render json: { message: 'ok' }, status: 200
rescue StandardError => e
  render json: { error: e.inspect }, status: 500
end
```

If it is a regular Rails controller/app, then I'd suggest to just redirect the user somewhere:

```
begin
  UsererMailer.with(user: @user).demo_request.deliver_now
  redirect_to some_path
rescue StandardError => e
  redirect_to some_path, error: e.inspect
end
```